# Is the second part of dialogue capitalized or not?

Tags: grammar, dialogue

i.e. "It is important," his mother replied, "(a/A)nd we will all have a great time."

Comment: Since it's a report of a dialogue, it depends on what his mother actually **said**. That is, did she say "It is important. [full stop intonation] And we will ...", or did she say "It is important, [comma intonation] and we will ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not unless the second part of the quote starts a new sentence," J.R. said. "In that case, you'd start with a capital letter.

"However, if both halves are part of the same sentence," J.R. continued, "then the second half begins with a lower-case letter."

See [Rule 4 at the Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/01/):

> **If a direct quotation is interrupted mid-sentence, do not capitalize the second part of the quotation.**
>
> *"I didn't see an actual alien being," Mr. Johnson said, "but I sure wish I had."*

Comment: But if a direct quotation is interrupted at the end of a sentence, capitalize the second part of the quotation. And the difference depends on the intonation.

Comment: ahh. just needed a clear-up.